# Exploiting SSTable order for random partitions queries

Tags: java, optimization, cassandra, datastax, cql

I need to optimize *one* read path of an application. Specifically, this application *sometimes* performs burst of reads, usually 8k requests of 4KB each. This read pattern usually sticks with *1 read per partition*, eg 8k requests *are* 8k rows, one row per partition.

Here's my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE myobjects (
    h blob,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (h)
);

CREATE TABLE mygroups (
    id uuid,
    sequence int,
    h blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, sequence)
);
```

Basically, I have a collection of objects, each identified by an hash in the `h` field, and a list of groups of objects. Each group consists of multiple objects, and the order in the database is dictated by the `sequence` field. **This is a lookup table approach**, no more, no less.

**Before you turn up your nose, I know I should denormalize blah blah**, but the amount of data in this scenario is fairy high, and we estimated that a lookup approach cuts down the storage costs, *considerably*.

Unfortunately, from the application point of view there's no way to change this read pattern.

This is not a good read pattern because it directly translates to random seeks on disks. Moreover, the application is going to run on spinning disks only and currently we have no plans on using SSDs.

Now, in order to optimize disk seeks I want to exploit the SSTable partition order. My reasoning is quite simple: if data in each SSTable is sorted by the token function, that is each SSTable can contain multiple partitions *ordered* by the TOKEN function, if I pre-sort the partition keys that need to be requested with the same function, I can exploit some sequentiality scans for each SSTable, saving precious disk seeks.

Here's what I've already tried:

```
BoundStatement selectGroupByUUID = ... 
ResultSet rs = ...

// Fetch all the rows
List<Row> rows = rs.all();

// Calculate the token for each row and sort by token order
TreeMap<Token, TreeSet<ByteBuffer>> tokenMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Row row : rows) {
    ByteBuffer hash = row.getBytes("h");
    Token token = metadata.newToken(hash);
    TreeSet<ByteBuffer> set = tokenMap.get(token);
    if (set == null) {
        set = new TreeSet<>();
        tokenMap.put(token, set);
    }
    set.add(hash);
}

// Request each hash in "token" order
TreeMap<ByteBuffer, Future<ResultSet>> resultSetMap = new TreeMap<>(); 
for (Map.Entry<Token, TreeSet<ByteBuffer>> tokenMapEntry : tokenMap.entrySet()) {
    TreeSet<ByteBuffer> set = tokenMapEntry.getValue();
    for (ByteBuffer hash : set) {
        Future<ResultSet> future = fetchObjectAsync(hash);
        resultSetMap.put(hash, future);
    }
}
```

What this code does is:

1. Fetch the list of object belonging to a group **G**
2. Calculate the token **T** for each `h` using the `metadata.newToken()` utility function of the Java DataStax Driver.
3. Add each set to a TreeMap ordered by `Token`
4. Iterate and request by token order, and inside each token by hash order.

It seems I'm missing something because this is not working properly, I see no benefits of this vs requesting hashes directly in sequence order.

I also understand that issuing a lot of IO concurrently allows the IO scheduler to optimize disk seeks too, but I saw no improvements even by changing queue depth & co....

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but on the subject of disks, a basic question as you're using rotational disks. Are you using a different disk for commitlog? Reason I ask is that if not then you might gain some by splitting data and commitlog to separate disks.

Comment: @markc The test machine is running on 2 HDDs in RAID0 only,but I'm performing reads and absolutely no writes...With a mixed workload a performance hit is expected.The deployment, however, should be on a 2x2TB HDDs + 2x250gbSSDs machines cluster.We plan to use HDDs to store data, SSDs to store commitlog and frequently queried/small CFs.

Comment: read repairs could create writes. As per your original question file system disk cache will be at play here. I dont think what you are doing here will make any noticeable difference to your read path.

Comment: What compaction strategy are you using? If the read has to hit 20 sstables this is all kinda moot.

Comment: @markc This is a one node only, I don't think any read repair stuff is happening. However, I'm convincing that all this is not going to be noticeable.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink SizeTiered. However I have only 3 sstables. Overwrites/column updates rarely happens, so each row is always on one table only. Tracing some queries confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

1. Although you are trying to read information based on token order - there is no grantee that they are actually in the same sstable file. Moreover each partition may be located in more then a single sstable.
2. When reading a key you may be accessing multiple files, index + data (if the information is not in the key cache) - so even if you have a single sstable, the fact that you need to go back to the index file and search for the data location may interfere with the assumed benefit.

Two options to get more inside information:

1. One item you can try is to trace this requests and check which sstable files are accessed during the query
2. If you are looking to understand the sequence of reads issued by a process (cassabdra) to read information you can use strace and capture the file access pattern